# Is a 3D renderer with 1000 FPS possible?

Tags: unity, unreal, vulkan

Okay, for my phD Thesis, I need to make a simple 3D game, like towers of hanoi or whatever but there is a condition:

I need it to have high FPS, as in, the highest FPS achievable, atleast a 1000FPS. I need to have a high FPS to measure reaction times. We achieve this with 1ms monitors BUT on the programming front, here is the problem,

1. I'm confused if I should code an entire specially made engine with only the features I need (using Vulkan), and if I did would it be faster than already available engines like Unity or Unreal? Would it be worth the time and effort or can these engines be customised themselves and is that easier than doing it from scratch?
2. Or is it only achievable with specialized hardware? So I'd be better of using an available engine and going hard on the hardware?

Comment: We don't do technology recommendations on this particular site. Fortunately, this is a question you can answer for yourself with profiling. All of the technologies you've listed are free to try. Set up a minimal project, and measure their framerate on your current hardware. That will tell you whether they're in the right ballpark, or if you need a hardware upgrade to pull it off. Since most games don't need to update and render every millisecond, you might not find game developers have a lot of tips about achieving this, and you're in academic research territory (as expected for a thesis).

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks that's what I thought.

Comment: How well do you need it to look? And is it relevant that the framerate is stable? Do you need 1000 FPS on average or do you need every single frame to not take more than 1ms to calculate?

Comment: You may be able to bring this question on-topic if you edit it to more it away from asking about specific technology, and toward "How do I solve my problem?" - In particular, if you can describe the reaction time measurement you need to do in more detail, we may be able to suggest other ways to achieve it even if you're not able to sustain 1000 fps.

Comment: Note that for 1000fps you need a monitor capable of showing 1000 frames per seconds, so a 1000hz montior. I don't think those exist. The 1ms you're referring to is how fast a pixel can change color. So how long it takes for a pixel to converge on the target color after the input was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could do that with e.g. C#, Java/Scala, C or Rust. But in order to run an engine at that frame rate, *all* of your per-frame processing - i.e. one game loop cycle - would need to *consistently fit into a 1 millisecond window* - this is practically impossible to achieve, even for simple games, and especially for those not familiar with optimising game loops.

You might want to look into high precision [hardware timers](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/hardware-timer) instead. You will need to see whether they are supported in your language of choice; certainly C will always have access to such timers, where they exist in the system at all. You would probably need to use a lower level language like C or Rust to achieve this.

To quote that link,

> In many cases you may just want to read the counter value to implement
> a simple delay function *that does not depend on the frequency* of the
> processor or speed *of executing a particular code sequence*.

That is, hardware timers are independent of the frequency of your loop, e.g. 1khz suggested.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it, hope you have a nice day.

Comment: I know that this question is closed. But I think you can easily fit a simple gameloop into a 1ms  window. The consistent part just means, making sure your application is never waiting (on GC or after sleeping) or interrupted. Which is achievable by not generating garbage (nor not using a GCd language) using busy waits instead of sleeps, and playing with processor affinity.

Comment: @Roy T. If there were no OS involved, or a very lightweight, custom kernel, and if you were writing C code (no GC), I might agree. Unfortunately, OS scheduling has impacts on **reliably** and **consistently** performing at such a high tick rate, so I would say no, it's really not possible when you need consistent results - as is the case for psychometric measurements the OP is trying to take. On the general OS of today, don't expect any miracles.

Comment: There's a 2004 3D networked fun racing game here seemingly hitting 950-1000 FPS with a "quite unoptimized" D3D9 engine (fixed function pipeline, no draw call sorting, no SSE, only what MSVC spits out in Release builds). Its "bottleneck" are the WinAPI `timeBeginPeriod(1)/timeGetTime` calls that do not allow to measure elapsed times less than 1 ms, so any time-dependent logic would not run more than 1000 times per second, and in fact a patch was added a few years ago to ignore 0ms updates to combat some carelessly coded things from breaking if no integrations happen.